# Store calendar week and year in one (date) column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, max

My table includes two columns: calendar week and year.
If I want to get the latest entries by calendar week and year, I currently perform:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE calyear = (SELECT MAX(calyear) FROM table) AND calweek = (SELECT MAX(calweek) FROM table WHERE calyear = (SELECT MAX(calyear) FROM table))`

which is super long. I'd like to replace this with a combination of week and year e.g. 'calweek-calyear' column. Is there a date format for that or should I save this as a tiny text?
I want to be able to perform MAX() on it and performance shouldn't suffer singificantly.
Im open for better solutions, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or SqlLite? You can create an integer that combines them though, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (CalYear * 100) + CalWeek = (SELECT MAX((CalYear * 100) + CalWeek) FROM table);`. However, if you are using a later version of MySQL then it may be better to use `RANK()` to identify the maximum rows, but it is not clear from the tags if you are even using MySQL, let alone a later version - [Various examples on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5piccLYaBvHeGzwiFguFHh/1)

Comment: @GarethD I use Mysql(corrected tags). Thanks for your comment/answer.

Comment: Please show output of `EXPLAIN PLAN ...` (with on the dots your query. An index might be missing. Also you only need 1 column when querying the current week (if that column has the `date` type, something like: `select d from dates where weekofyear(d)=6 and year(d)=2022;` would get the current week.

Comment: What is your definition of week? [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) definition? Some other definition?

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate YYYYWW in a column TINYTEXT, or other text type  I think it will do what you want.
If you make sure that your week numbers are 2 digit ie 01 and not 1 you could use INT.
I would rather advise the use of a column DATE and a modified query.

Answer (score 0):

Your *super long* query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY calyear DESC, calweek DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

if you expect only 1 row as a result.

If there are more than 1 rows for the max `calyear` and `calweek` combination, you could use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY calyear DESC, calweek DESC) rnk
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1;
```

Also, I would advice against the use of a combination of year and week. 
Keep your data as simple as possible.
For presentation purposes you could easily concatenate the 2 columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this right away. I use mysql.